# Demonstrate that $p(x)=q(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

I want to demonstrate the following statement.

> Let $p,q\in \mathbb{GF}_2[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be of degree $n$ such that for all $v_1,\ldots,v_n\in\mathbb{GF}_2$, $p(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=q(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$. Prove that $p=q$.

I started by showing that if $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are all equal to 0 then the know terms of $p$ and $q$ are equal. So $p(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=q(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$.
Now I want to demonstrate the same thing for all the other coefficient.

How I can proceed?

I was thinking to proceed to do the same thing with the coefficient of the monomials of degree one and so on,  just by showing with a proper combination of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ that the coefficient are all the same. The only problem is that I don't know how to elegantly write this(or just in a "math" way).

It seems that I wasn't very cleary about my statment.
I'll write and example so maybe it's more clear what I'm trying to do.
$$p(x_1,x_2)= a_1+b_{11}x_1+b_{12}x_2+c_1x_1x_2$$
$$q(x_1,x_2)= a_2+b_{21}x_1+b_{22}x_2+c_2x_1x_2$$
Now I want to prove that if

$p(0,0)=q(0,0),p(1,0)=q(1,0),p(0,1)=q(0,1),p(1,1)=q(1,1)$

then

$a_1=a_2, b_{11}=b_{21},b_{12}=b_{22}, c_1=c_2$

because:

$p(0,0)=q(0,0) \Rightarrow a_1=a_2$

then 
$p(1,0)=q(1,0) \Rightarrow b_{11}=b_{21}$ because we already know that ($a_1=a_2$)

and so on

Comment: @malloc what space do the coefficients of the polynomial belong to? And for the proof, my hint is the following: $p-q$ is a polynomial. Can you prove that it is the zero polynomial?

Comment: @DonThousand $\mathbb{GF}(2)$, but I think that it's not important(should be equal on every field if the variables are on $\mathbb{GF}(2)$ right?)

Comment: @DonThousand I think that should be what I'm asking. This is my general polinomial $p(t_1,\ldots, t_n) = a +\sum_{1\leq h \leq n} a_h t_h+\sum_{1\leq h < k\leq n} a_{h,k}t_ht_k  +\ldots + a_{1,\ldots,n}t_1\ldots t_n$ and all the $t$s and the $a$s are defined over $\mathbb{GF}(2)$

Comment: @DonThousand to be clear p(0,0)=q(0,0), p(0,1)=q(0,1), p(1,0)=q(1,0) p(1,1)=q(1,1) and then I want to prove that the coefficient of the two polynomimal are equal. I don't know If it's clear.(Like you can see I'm not a math student) all with 2 variables and polynomials of degree 2

Comment: the example was with 2 variables and polynomials of degree 2

Comment: The assertion doesn't seem true to me. What if $p(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_1$ and $q(x_1,x_2)=x_2^2+x_2$?

Comment: @GregMartin the variables are on $\mathbb{GF}(2)$ so $x_1^2=x_1$ and in your example $p(x_1,x_2)$ and $q(x_1,x_2)$ will be equal to $0$ since $x_1^2+x_1=x_1+x_1=0$

Comment: What is your definition of polynomials being equal then? From your comment it sounds like you are defining polynomials to be equal if all of their values are equal—but that make the assertion in the OP true by definition.

Comment: I don't believe the statement you're trying to prove is true in general either. Let $\ p=x_1^2+x_2^2\ $ and $\ q=x_1+x_2^2\ $.  Then $\ p,q\in\mathbb{GF}_2[x_1,x_2]\ $ are of degree $2$, and
$$
p(0,0)=0=q(0,0)\\
p(0,1)=1=q(0,1)\\
p(1,0)=1=q(1,0)\\
p(1,1)=0=q(1,1)\ .
$$
But $\ p\ne q\ $.  Are you sure you've stated the  condition on $\ p\ $ and $\ q\ $ correctly?   Perhaps it should be something like $\ p\left(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\right)=$$q \left(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\right)\ $ for all $\ v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\in\mathbb{GF}_{2^\color{red}n} $.

Comment: @GregMartin I didn't say that the polynomials should be equal, but I said that the solution of the polynomials are equals and so the coefficient of it should be equal. Maybe with all the edit this was lost. (I hope that it's more clear now). For example $p(0)=q(0), p(1)=q(1) \Rightarrow p(x)=a_1x+b_1=a_2x+b_2=q(x) \Rightarrow a_1=a_2 \quad b_1=b_2$

Comment: If you are saying that polynomial equality means that all coefficients are equal, then $x_1^2$ and $x_1$ are not the same polynomial at all—their degree-1 and degree-2 coefficients both differ. Similarly for $x_1^2+x_1$ and $0$.

Comment: @GregMartin I don't know if I've understood correctly here. Why $x_1^2$ and $x_1$ are not equal?(Sorry If I don't undestand quicly). I write the degree-2 coefficient like this $x_ix_j$(es $x_1x_2$) because $x_1^2=x_1$ in the finite field $\mathbb{GF}_2$ (or not?).

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I don't understand why you write $x_1^2$. Isn't it equal to $x_1$? (es $x=0$ then $x^2=0$ and if $x=1$ then $x^2=1$ so $x^2=x$ right?)

Comment: @GregMartin I've edited a little my question, let me know if it's more clear now

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I've edited a little my question, let me know if it's more clear now

Comment: If $q$ is a prime power, then in $\mathbb{F}_q[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$ the ideal of polynomials which evaluate to 0 everywhere is generated by $x_1^q - x_1, \ldots, x_n^q - x_n$.  The leading terms of each are pairwise relatively prime, so this also forms a Groebner basis of the ideal.  Therefore, the minimum degree of a nonzero element of the ideal is $q$.

Comment: @malloc According to the standard definition of polynomials over any field, finite or not, the indeterminates appearing in any polynomial are *not* elements of the field itself, and different powers $x_i^m,x_i^n, m\ne n$ of any indeterminate are *different* polynomials regardless of whether $v^m=v^n$ for all members $v$ of the field. If you were to regard $x_i^m$ as being equal to $x_i^n$ merely because $v^m=v^n$ for all $v\in\mathbb{GF}_2$, then there would only be four univariate polynomials over $\mathbb{GF}_2$, namely $\ 0,1,x,$ and $1+x$, and none of degree greater than $1$.

Comment: Thus, as long as you write "Prove $\ p=q\ $" you are using a *non-standard* notion of equality of polynomials and whatever it is you're trying to prove will remain confusing. What you *apparently* mean is that, if $\ p\ $ or $\ p−1\ $ is a [*multilinear* polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_polynomial), and $\ q\ $ or $\ q−1\ $ is a *multilinear* polynomial, both in $\ n\ $ indeterminates, and $\ p(v)=q(v)\ $ for all $\ v\in\mathbb{GF}_2^n\ $, then $\ p=q\ $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the OP is apparently asking for is a proof that if $\ p\ $ and $\ q\ $ are polynomials over $\ \mathbb{GF}_2\ $ of the form
\begin{align}
p&=\sum_{S\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\}}\pi_S\prod_\limits{i\in S}x_i\ \text{ and }\\
q&= \sum_{S\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\}}\xi_S\prod_\limits{i\in S}x_i\ ,
\end{align}
and $\ p\left(v\right)= q\left(v\right)\ $ for all $\ v\in \mathbb{GF}_2^n\ $, then $\ p=q\ $. This follows from the fact that if we define $\ w_S\in \mathbb{GF}_2^n\ $ by
$$
w_{Si}=\cases{1&if $\ i\in S$\\
           0&if $\ i\not\in S\ $}
$$
for any $\ S\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\} $, then $\ p\left(w_S\right)=\pi_S\ $ and $\ q\left(w_S\right)=\xi_S\ $, which gives $\ \pi_S=\xi_S\ $ for all $\ S\ $, and hence $\ p=q\ $.